# C# Searching a txt file for match and returning the rest of the line

Tags: c#, file, text

To make it more clear, I have a txt file that looks like this

```
326785, Dan Humphrey
284728, Serena Van Der Woodsen
```

I'm searching the numbers before the names in the txt file. If I search for "326785", I want it to return "Dan Humphrey".

I think I'm supposed to used split method for this but I'm not exactly sure how.

I check if the id and passhash exists in another txt file which contains id's and password hashes but I have to return what record it corresponds to in the other txt file that contains id numbers and names as I've mentioned above.

```
 public bool authenticator(string id, string hashedUserPassword)
    {
        string path = ("C:\\Banka\\auth.txt");
        var result = IsStringInFile(path,hashedUserPassword,id);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `1)` Read your text file line by line `2)` Search your `326785` in your lines with `String.Contains` or `String.IndexOf` methods. `3)` Get's the line you found it. `4)` Use `String.Split` to to get your name.

Comment: Check the split function.

Comment: @sonergönül does the string.contains or string.indexof methods get the line?

Comment: @user3698687 No. These methods search a string in another string. They return `boolean` or `int` values in order. Read [How to: Read Text from a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You want smething like this?

```
public string SearchText(string s)
{

    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if(line.Contains(s)){
            var l = line.Split(',');
            return l[1];
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: A small adjustment on this code, don't do the spit. First check your line for the text. Now you're splitting your string which isn't necessarly needed. 1 statement to much :)

Comment: I won't have much impact, but omtimalization is optimalization :-)

Comment: getting an error "identifier expected" on  this line var l= line.Split.-errorhere-(',');

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your file is the same on all the lines (a number followed by a colon and then the name) you can read the file line by line and split it on the ',' character.

Then you check if the first part matches your searched string, and if so, you return the 2nd part.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the line as a string, split into two strings with "."
2. Push into an entity(if really needed)
3. If your number is equal to the extracted string(ie., splittedString[0]), then display/fetch the splittedString[1]